# How to not show navigation bar when routing Nativescript (Angular)

Tags: angular, nativescript

Good day,

I want to create a login and register page in Nativescript. But when i use (see code below)

`this.router.navigate(["/register"]);`

it shows me the register page in a navigation with a back button. How do i remove the top navigation. I tried the code below:

`this.router.navigateByUrl("/register", { clearHistory: true });`

But when i use the code above it disappears but u see the white bar for about a second before it disappears. How do i make it smooth and not show at all after navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide the actionbar in your components using the following:

```js
import { Page } from '@nativescript/core';

...

constructor(private page: Page) {
  page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smooth experience, do the following in your register component.

Add the `flat` attribute to the `ActionBar` tag.

HTML:

```
<ActionBar flat="true">
    <Label text=" "></Label>
</ActionBar>
```

Then set the color of the ActionBar to the color of your register page's background color(Eg: white).

CSS:

```
ActionBar {
    background-color: #00b33c;
}
```